# CUDA - Calling a Kernel Multiple Times

Tags: c, cuda, reduction

I'm having difficulty with a CUDA program I'm trying to write.  I have an array of about 524k floating point values (1.0) and I'm using reduction technique to add all the values.  The problem works fine if I only want to run it once, but I really want to run the kernel several times so that I can sum up over 1 billion values eventually.

The reason I am doing this in chunks of 524k is that I always get zeroes back when I go over about 1 million on the gpu.  That shouldn't exceed the memory on the card, but it always fails at that point.

Anyway, when I loop the kernel only one time, everything works fine.  That is, no looping is fine.  When I go run with loops, it comes back with zeroes.  I suspect I'm going out of bounds some place, but I cannot figure it out.  It's driving me nuts.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks,

Al

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "cutil.h"

#define TILE_WIDTH     512
#define WIDTH          524288 
//#define WIDTH          1048576
#define MAX_WIDTH      524288

#define BLOCKS         WIDTH/TILE_WIDTH

__global__ void PartSum(float * V_d)
{
   int tx = threadIdx.x;
   int bx = blockIdx.x;

   __shared__ float partialSum[TILE_WIDTH];

   for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH/TILE_WIDTH; ++i)
   {
      partialSum[tx] = V_d[bx * TILE_WIDTH + tx];
      __syncthreads();


      for(unsigned int stride = 1; stride < blockDim.x; stride *= 2)
      {
         __syncthreads();
         if(tx % (2 * stride) == 0)
            partialSum[tx] += partialSum[tx + stride];
      }
   }

   if(tx % TILE_WIDTH == 0)
      V_d[bx * TILE_WIDTH + tx] = partialSum[tx];
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
   float * V_d;
   float * V_h;
   float * R_h;
   float * Result;
   float * ptr;

   dim3 dimBlock(TILE_WIDTH,1,1);
   dim3 dimGrid(BLOCKS,1,1);

   // Allocate memory on Host
   if((V_h = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * WIDTH)) == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error allocating memory on host\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   if((R_h = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * MAX_WIDTH)) == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error allocating memory on host\n");
      exit(-1);
   }

   // If MAX_WIDTH is not a multiple of WIDTH, this won't work
   if(WIDTH % MAX_WIDTH != 0)
   {
      printf("The width of the vector must be a multiple of the maximum width\n");
      exit(-3);
   }

   // Initialize memory on host with 1.0f
   ptr = V_h;
   for(long long i = 0; i < WIDTH; ++i)
   {
      *ptr = 1.0f;
      ptr = &ptr[1];
   }

   ptr = V_h;

   // Allocate memory on device in global memory
   cudaMalloc((void**) &V_d, MAX_WIDTH*(sizeof(float)));
   float Pvalue = 0.0f;
   for(int i = 0; i < WIDTH/MAX_WIDTH; ++i)
   {


   if((Result = (float *) malloc(sizeof(float) * WIDTH)) == NULL)
   {
      printf("Error allocating memory on host\n");
      exit(-4);
   }

   for(int j = 0; j < MAX_WIDTH; ++j)
   {
      Result[j] = *ptr;
      ptr = &ptr[1];
   }

      ptr = &V_h[i*MAX_WIDTH];
      // Copy portion of data to device
      cudaMemcpy(V_d, Result, MAX_WIDTH*(sizeof(float)), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

      // Execute Kernel
      PartSum<<<dimGrid, dimBlock>>>(V_d);

      // Copy data back down to host
      cudaMemcpy(R_h, V_d, MAX_WIDTH*(sizeof(float)), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

      for(int i = 0; i < MAX_WIDTH; i += TILE_WIDTH)
      {
         Pvalue += R_h[i];
      }
printf("Pvalue == %f\n", Pvalue);

  free(Result);


   }

//   printf("WIDTH == %d items\n", WIDTH);
//   printf("Value: %f\n", Pvalue);

   cudaFree(V_d);
   free(V_h);
   free(R_h);
   return(1);
}
```

Okay, I think I've narrowed down the problem to be with V_d on the device.  I suspect I'm exceeding the bounds of the array some how.  If I allocate 2 times the amount of memory I actually need, the program finish with the expected results.  The problem is, I cannot figure out what is causing the problems.

Al

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost ? Since you want to more iterations of your kernel, you might consider using `cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice` instead.

Comment: I can't believe you actually need CUDA for this - it's going to be pretty much I/O dominated since you just have one add operation per point - you might as well just use the CPU. Have you actually benchmarked a CPU implementation of this implementation ? How much faster do you think a CUDA implementation might be, given that it's all data movement and virtually no computation ?

Comment: This is a learning experiment for me.  I realize this is not efficient.

Comment: @karlphillip: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: You are transferring memory to the GPU back and forth. I think it's unecessary to transfer data to the CPU on each iteration.

Comment: @karlphillip: Okay, I understand and I agree. I plan on correcting that after I get the multiple iterations problem fixed.  thx.

Comment: I have run into an interesting problem.  In the above, I'm creating an array of float dynamically using cudaMalloc.  I start running into problems when I approach memory allocations of around 1 million.  However, when I declare an array of float using __device__ and then copy the values to the array, I experience no difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

I think I spotted the first bug here:

```
  if(tx % TILE_WIDTH == 0)
      V_d[bx * TILE_WIDTH + tx] = partialSum[tx];
```

The range of **tx** is 0-511 and it never reached 512. So the **if** condition will never be true. You can write it as **if(tx % (TILE_WIDTH-1) == 0)**.

Comment: Ah! I didn't see that!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, thanks to everyone who gave this a look and any help.

Second, I finally figured out what I was doing wrong.  `BLOCKS` should have been defined as `MAX_WIDTH/TILE_WIDTH`, not `WIDTH/TILE_WIDTH`.  Stupid, silly mistake from my part.

Thanks again.